# Physical reason for modified resolving power for circular apertures

Tags: optics, diffraction, wavelength

It is rather easy to see Rayleigh's criterion leads to $\theta=\lambda/L$ for resolving power of rectangular aperture. On the other hand, this relation for circular apertures translates to $\theta=1.22 \lambda/L$ where $L$ is the diameter of circle. Now I like to know whether is possible to justify factor $1.22$ physically.

It seems light sees a shorter diameter. Am I right?

Comment: See [the Wikipedia article on the Airy disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk). $1.22\lambda/d$ is the value of $\sin\theta$ at which the first minimum in the diffraction pattern occurs, so it is only a rough guide to the resolution.

Comment: Apodization filters can increase the resolution slightly beyond the diffraction limit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apodization#Apodization_in_optics

Comment: @safesphere The word is "resolution" is frequently misunderstood because of overuse. I think calling the effect of apodization improved resolution is misleading and is a misnomer, it should be called improving contrast or something like that.

Comment: @hyportnex You can call it whatever works for you best, although I thought the resolution limit was defined via contrast, so "tomayto - tomahto" :) My point is that apodization makes a huge difference in photography. In art photography the main improvement is not the resolution, but bokeh. In physics terms, it translates to a reduction of lines around the out of focus  edges and dramatically improves the subjective impression.

Comment: @JohnRennie You're right, but I thought it can be somehow compared with rectangular aperture.

Comment: @MEDVIS: the [diffraction pattern of a rectangular aperture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction_equation#Rectangular_aperture) differs from that of a circular aperture. That's all that's going on here.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/696980/2451 and links therein.