# Where does the 1.22 come from in Rayleigh criterion for circular apertures?

Tags: optics, diffraction, wavelength

For the formula 1.22, $\lambda/b$, which describes the angle at which resolution occurs, where does the 1.22 come from? I have looked at the derivation and there doesn't seem to be any explanation?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you are asking because if you have followed the derivation then the answer is there: 1.22 is where the Bessel function has the first zero, and the Bessel function arises from the Fourier transform of the aperture function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The light intensity pattern cast by a circular hole of radius $a$
is the so-called [Airy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk#Mathematical_formulation)
$$I(\theta)=I_0 \left[\frac{2J_1(ka\sin\theta)}{ka\sin\theta}\right]^2$$
where $J_1(x)$ is the first [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1)
and $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ is the wave number of the light.

The first minimum of this pattern obviously is at
$$J_1(ka\sin\theta)=0.$$

Since the first zero of the Bessel function $J_1(x)$ is at $x=3.83$ you get
$$ka\sin\theta=3.83$$

With the wave number $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ and diameter $b=2a$ this becomes
$$\sin\theta=\frac{3.83}{\pi}\frac{\lambda}{b}=1.22\frac{\lambda}{b}$$

Now two neighboring Airy patterns are barely resolvable when the maximum of
one Airy pattern is at the minimum of the other Airy pattern.
Hence the resolution limit is also given by
$$\sin\theta=1.22\frac{\lambda}{b}$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, a quick look at Wikipedia's entry for Rayleigh Criterion yields:

> This number is more precisely 1.21966989... (OEIS: A245461), the first zero of the order-one Bessel function of the first kind $J_1(x)$ divided by π.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked

> where does the factor of 1.22 come from?

An easy-to-understand approach is to model the aperture as an evenly-distributed disk of point sources.

Even a relatively small number of sources (here about 250) gives a good approximation to the first minimum occurring at about $1.22\frac{\lambda}d$

[image: plot showing source positions and beam angles for first and second minima]